# Update laravel with GitHub

Tags: laravel, github

Is there any way to upgrade Laravel project with GitHub?

## Example:

I have my project uploaded in GitHub as private or public then every time that a file(s) changed in there I want to get the update notification in my live app and by clicking update button my current files in server be replaced with files in GitHub.

## Questions

1. Is this possible?
2. Are there any packages for this matter or I need to write my custom codes?

Comment: This is pretty much what _continuous integration / continuous deployment_ is used for. Any reason you want to do this manually instead of using already available solutions like jenkins?

Comment: @Namoshek no i just thought if there is no package for it i am open to receive custom solutions both ways are good for me as long as it works

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to put your own CI/CD system (like Jenkins) and a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) listening to [push events](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#events)... you can use [GitHub actions](https://github.com/features/actions), by [creating a workflow](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-workflow-with-github-actions).

You have many examples [listed here](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions), an [introduction there](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/introducing-github-actions).

This [example listens to push](https://github.com/repetitive/actions/tree/master/auto-pull-request) and can then send a message to your application.

Comment: this is on github side processing, how do i introduce it into laravel side?

Comment: @mafortis By sending a message to your application, which will be listening for such message.

Comment: i think you got me wrong, I can handle message in my laravel app for message part i don't need github all i need is to my app check changes in github if there is then i can execute custom message by session::flash .

Comment: @mafortis "check changes in GitHub": either a webhook (as I mention in the beginning of the answer) or a GitHub action: "changes in GitHub" is a "GitHub side" event.

Comment: @mafortis When github points URL of webhook, there in that controller method you would call something like [symfony process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) component and finish the job.

Comment: Don't make your application self-updating if you can use CI/CD... it is a waste of time and it is way more error prone.

Comment: @Namoshek I don't want to make it self-update i want let users decide to upgrade or not but at least i need to inform them about new versions and in case they want to upgrade allow them to download files. (still didn't understand this answer :/)

Comment: Ok, so you want something like WordPress is using? You most likely wouldn't be doing that through GitHub directly. I think you'll need some sort of _version reference file_ somewhere, which is read by the application to determine which new versions are available.

Comment: @Namoshek that's right, i can have that version file in my own host that's not a problem.

Comment: Anyway, that's a way too broad question in my opinion. But there are already blog posts with tutorials out there if you look for `php self update like wordpress` for example.